# twig and wordpress sanitise &amp; twice

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twig

A Wordpress plugin I'm working on uses the Twig templating language.

I want to output a list of categories to a template. I get them from the WP database like so:

`$terms = get_terms( 'groups' );`

In the Twig template, I want to output each term:

```
{% for term in terms %}
    <a href="{{ term.slug }}">{{ term.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is, one of my `term.name`s is 'HIV & AIDS', and it gets sanitised both by `get_terms()` and by Twig, which results in 'HIV &amp; AIDS'.

I've tried using `preg_replace` to clean it after the `get_terms()` stage:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $terms ); $i++ )
{
    $terms[$i].name = preg_replace('/amp;/', '', $terms[$i]);
}
```

Although this is OK when there's just one set of terms on the page, in fact there are several other places where I have to display the terms, including a page heading and several more times in the page content.

So, the question is, is there a 'right' way to prevent Wordpress and Twig from sanitising the & (ampersand) character twice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the values as is in Twig, you can use the `raw` filter. Default all values will be escaped.

```
{{ term.name|raw }}
```

See: [Twig raw filter](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html)